# cabal build Out of Memory Mac VS Code Docker

Tags: cabal, vscode, docker, macos

This is a follow up to my previous cabal build problem. I ran cabal update. Then cabal build was killed. I tried increasing Docker memory from 2GB to 3GB. My old Mac has 8GB, Activity Monitor peaked at 6.7GB

Completed ouroboros-network-framework-0.1.0.0 (lib)
cabal: Failed to build cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0 (which is required by
exe:plutus-starter-pab from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0 and
test:plutus-example-projects-test from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0). The build
process was killed (i.e. SIGKILL). The typical reason for this is that there
is not enough memory available (e.g. the OS killed a process using lots of
memory).
Failed to build iohk-monitoring-0.2.0.0 (which is required by
exe:plutus-starter-pab from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0 and
test:plutus-example-projects-test from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0). The build
process was killed (i.e. SIGKILL). The typical reason for this is that there
is not enough memory available (e.g. the OS killed a process using lots of
memory).

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to build this in less than 8G of RAM. Adding swap to make the total memory at least 8G may help.